# Getting error in flutter compilation like : carousel_slider-4.2.0/lib/carousel_slider.dart:311:29: Error: Member not found: 'trackpad'

Tags: flutter, compiler-errors, flutter-dependencies

I am getting error while compiling flutter app
Anyone can help?
Here is full error :

```
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/carousel_slider-4.2.0/lib/carousel_slider.dart:311:29: Error: Member not found: 'trackpad'.
          PointerDeviceKind.trackpad
```

Here are dependencies from yaml file
`

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
sdk: ">=2.16.2 <3.0.0"

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  carousel_slider: ^4.2.0
  video_player:
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome Rohan!

This issue is because of the introduction of the new trackpad gestures in version 3.3.0-0.0.pre of flutter as documented here: https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/trackpad-gestures looks like carousel_slider has been update to use it.

You have two options:

1. Upgrade your flutter SDK to 3.3.0-0.0.pre or greater
2. Or downgrade carousel_slider: 4.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Clean `pub` cache folder by command bellow

```
flutter pub cache repair
```

And download all dependencies by following command in your project directory

```
flutter pub cache repair
```

**IMPORTANT**

All libraries will be downloaded from the internet from the scratch and this will take some time depends how many libraries are you using

Comment: I tried it but again same error getting

Answer (score 0):

you should declare `carousel_slider: 4.1.1` in pubspec.yaml
instead of `carousel_slider: ^4.1.1` because with `^` sign flutter will try to use latest version in pub.dev